# AlfrescoRuntimeException: 01100031 GetModelsDiff return status is 404

Tags: tomcat, alfresco, runtimeexception

The problem is in the title. after alfresco starts there is the following exception in the catalina.out file:

```
ERROR [solr.tracker.CoreTracker] [SolrTrackerScheduler_Worker-1] Tracking failed
 org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 01100031 GetModelsDiff return status is 404
    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1059)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackModels(CoreTracker.java:1897)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.trackRepository(CoreTracker.java:1227)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTracker.updateIndex(CoreTracker.java:513)
    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.CoreTrackerJob.execute(CoreTrackerJob.java:45)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

I looked at [this theme](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/installation-upgrades/04070101-getmodelsdiff) but didn't understand much and the what I understood didn't help.

I must say that I'm trying to start tomcat with my alfresco.war at the server with the centOS installed. When I've tryed to start tomcat with my alfresco.war on my windows it worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reinstalling alfresco solved the problem

Comment: Same here ; re-installing alfresco fixed the issue. I don't know why it happens and why can we not find out the root cause.

Comment: Did anyone came across the root cause of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you create a new content model and upload content of particular type or add newly created aspect in the new uploded content,after that if you remove content model and start server It will throw the exception which you have specified.Because the new uploaded content will not find aspect or type.

For resolution of above you need to remove alfdata and database or reinstall alfrersco.Or else place same content model in your alfresco instance.

In above example ,error will also be thrown if you rename the namespace uri in content model.

Comment: you mean remove this: Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\alfresco, Alfresco\tomcat\webapps\share? this didn't helped. I didn't change anything after deploing on windows - everything is the same

Comment: no you need to remove database and alf_data...check your alfresco-global.properties it shows the location of alf_data.If you delete those things Every thing will get removed , all your document and metadata.

Comment: clearing alf_data gives nothing but other exceptions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70628/discussion-between-krutik-jayswal-and-nikitin-mikhail).

Answer (score 1):

May this helps, disable the POST buffer limit in the Tomcat SSL connector definition. Open {TOMCAT_HOME}/conf/server.xml and set maxSavePostSize=-1 as shown below.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol" 
SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https" 
keystoreFile="XXXXXXX" keystorePass="XXXXXXX" keystoreType="JCEKS" secure="true" connectionTimeout="240000" truststoreFile="XXXXXXX" 
truststorePass="XXXXXXX" truststoreType="JCEKS"
 clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" maxSavePostSize="-1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue.

For my installation I copied a vm and changed the ip address of the vm. Alfresco had stored the hostname and was using it to make calls, which makes sense why reinstalling alfresco solved the problem. Since the hostname was no longer mapped to the correct address it got the error while trying to call some of it's services.

To fix it I updated my hosts file to reflect the ip address change.

Although the issue might not be the same for everyone an ip address change or hostname change might be the cause of the problem.